# undefined reference to `writen'

Tags: c, sockets, linker, serversocket

I am learning socket programming and currently working on an ECHO server code. I am getting these errors :

> serverecho.c:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to 'writen'
>   serverecho.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to 'print'

while compiling. I am not sure what I have done wrong in this. My code's below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SA  struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int roockfd, confd;
    pid_t childpid;
    socklen_t len;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    roockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(roockfd, (SA *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(roockfd, 5);

    for (; ;) {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);

        confd = accept(roockfd, (SA *)&cliaddr, &len);
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
                           ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));
        if ((childpid=fork())==0)
        {   
            close(roockfd);
            echoserv(confd);
            exit(0);
        }

        close(confd);
    }
}

echoserv(int sockfd)   /* echoserv function */
{
    ssize_t n;
    char buff[MAXLINE];

again :
    while((n=read(sockfd,buff,MAXLINE)>0))
        writen(sockfd,buff,n);

        if(n<0)
            print("Error while reading");
}
```

Error while compiling with gcc :

> root@kali:~/Desktop/cprogs# gcc serverecho.c -o serverecho.out -lm
>       /tmp/ccWL7GLc.o: In function 'echoserv':
>       serverecho.c:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to 'writen'
>       serverecho.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to 'print'
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Typos: `writen` -> `write` and `print` -> `printf`.

Comment: There's no `print` in the standard library, there are `(f)printf` and `(f)puts`.

Comment: what is `writen`? what is `print`? I don't know these C functions?

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled, and treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
write(sockfd,buff,n);
```

because `writen` is not a predefined function in C. So, when you compile your program, you are getting an undefined reference to `writen'.

Also do `printf("Error while reading");` instead of `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code. Instead of `writen` use `write` and instead of `print` use `printf`. If you do not refer to these functions, make sure to include them properly such that the compiler knows where to find them.